# Executing a remote command

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, remote, aws

1. I can't edit the .bashrc of the fs I'm connecting to
2. I have to use the `~/.ssh/config` file

Here is my current config:

```
Host my-ssh
HostName <ip>
User <user>
IdentityFile <file location>
Compression yes
RemoteCommand cd <path to folder>
```

When I run `ssh my-ssh` nothing happens. The connection seems to automatically close. If I remove the `RemoteCommand` line it connects without an issue.

Is this something on the server config? It's an EC2 instance, either CentOS or RHEL and bash is the shell.

Comment: The list you've entered is in a desktop shortcut?  
`man ssh` to find out how to specify those items on a command line.  
Is this homework?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you specify a remote command, then the ssh connection is going to close as soon as the remote command exits. A `cd` command will exit almost immediately.

A common way to do what you want is:

```
RemoteCommand cd /some/path && bash
```

(Substitute your desired shell in place of "bash"). This cd's to the path and then invokes a subshell if the cd operation succeeded. The ssh connection will close when the subshell exits.

You will also want to force ssh to allocate a PTY for the session:

```
RequestTTY yes
```

If you don't, then ssh won't request one by default, and you'll get a non-interactive shell session. Notably, you won't get a command prompt.

Comment: You can enter a shell and stay there if you use `RequestTTY yes`. For me using ```  RequestTTY yes
  RemoteCommand zsh
``` works. Without RequestTTY, the connection hangs up.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a `RemoteCommand` specified it is the same as the following:

```
ssh user@host <command>
```

What happens is that `ssh` connects to the host, runs the command and exits, and returns the exit status of the command as the exit status of `ssh`.

From the man page:

> If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell.

So you are logging into the host, changing directory and then `ssh` is exiting. I doubt this is what you want. Remote command is non-interactive, i.e. to run one specific command on a remote machine.

Answer (score -2):

Try to run `ssh -t my-ssh`. You may need to force pseudo terminal allocation which is ommitted by the config in ~/.ssh/config.

Comment: this is not complete, as the asker needs also to do something more than just issuing a `cd ...` (which then exits, ending the session)